# running sudo command in bash script and running it with launchd

Tags: macos, bash, launchd

I have a bash script that I would like to run with a launchd plist file on OS X. The problem I have is is that the bash script contains sudo commands and it is stopping it from running. So for example my bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /opt/local/bin/bindfs -u user1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/user1 /vhosts/user1/public_html
sudo /opt/local/bin/bindfs -u user2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/user2 /vhosts/user2/public_html
```

and my com.test.bindfs.plist file looks like this (created with Lingon):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>admin</string>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.jamespayne.bindfs</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/bindfs.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have checked to see that the script works by running it after startup and entering a password but it wont run at startup. The launchd plist is running but it comes up with the following error:

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Anybody know how to get this working or why I might get that error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` is an interactive command, requiring the user the enter their password in order to proceed.  I would imagine that `sudo`, being unable to find a tty, simply exits with an error.

The command you want is `su`, which is non-interactive, with the only exception being you need to be root to run it.  However in your case you probably don't need it at all given the script is being run by an privileged user anyway?

Also why are you putting scripts into `/usr/bin`?  Bad idea; use `/usr/local/bin` instead (or `/usr/local/sbin` if it exists).

Comment: Thanks for the security tip. Moved.

Answer (score 6):

You can probably just move the property list to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and remove the sudo commands from the script.

See `man launchd`, `man launchd.plist`, and [this blog post](http://nb.nathanamy.org/2012/07/schedule-jobs-using-launchd/).

Comment: Although this is what I ended up doing and it solved the problem, I will have to accept trojanfoe's answer because it specifically addresses and explains the problems associated with the original script. I have up voted your answer anyway because it is a relevant alternative.

Answer (score 3):

If you've come here from Google looking to run a user login LaunchAgent with sudo/root privileges you can do the following:

- Put the plist in `/Library/LaunchAgents` if running for all users or `~/Library/LaunchAgents` if running for just a single user
- Have the first `ProgramArguments` be `sudo`, and the remaining be the command you are running
- Set the `NOPASSWORD` configuration in a `/etc/sudoers.d` file to allow `launchctl` to escalate your specific command without an interactive password prompt.

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/288322/22055) for a more detailed step-by-step walkthrough.